# ESB solution test performance & benchmarking

Tags: wso2, soa, esb, tibco, talend

I'm currently doing a study on SOA, and tools to implement it. please I would like to have a list comparative of ESB solution on the market (open source and commercial licence including cost). and also if possible a good tutorials for good implementation of an ESB.

Comment: this question is not a good fit for Q&A.

Comment: Your comment begs the question, where would be a constructive place for this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you would be interested and find following information helpful.

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65

http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-worlds-fastest-esb-was-made.html

http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2012/09/busting-synapse-and-wso2-esb-myths.html